# Fade Out/In Animation React Navigation

Tags: react-native, android-animation, android-transitions, react-navigation-v6

I am developing a React Native application using REACT NAVIGATION V6. I would like to add a custom transition for my navigation: fade out the current screen -> fade in the new screen. Any help on how I can achieve these transitions will be appreciated. Thanks

I have tried different solutions including cardInterpolation and transitionPresets but am unable to achieve the said behaviour

Comment: Hello, can you provide part of code where you implement transitionPresets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these line no need to add cardInterpolation and transitionPresets.

```
screenOptions={{
 animation: 'fade',
 animationDuration: 2000,
}}
```

in your stack navigation or particular screen option, it may fix your problem.

[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BnBRT4RMj5I0I2XA3WBjQik86zfyZRsX/view?usp=sharing)